# Como ler e converter CSV com listas agrupadas por colchetes {} (dicionários) no R

Tags: r, lista, csv

Eu tenho um arquivo csv de 18 regiões com a contagem (frequência) de ocorrência de determinados digital number (DN) que foram obtidos no Google Earth Engine. Porém, aparentemente, os dados em CSV vieram armazenados em uma lista por cada região.

Na primeira linha eu tenho o seguinte:

> "1    {33=67674.65490196079, 3=1155012.4039215685, 4=976901.0274509805,
> 15=58231.86666666672, 12=1578611.0196078431, 21=4.0,
> 11=276617.8666666667, 0=533990.0705882354}"

Note que na primeira linha temos 8 DN (33, 3, 4, 15, 12, 21, 11 e 0) com as respectivas frequências para a região 1.

Eu gostaria de ler e converter esse arquivo em um data.frame, semelhante a isto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Cada região tem DNs diferentes, ou seja, não ha um padrão esperado.

a fonte de dados reprodutível pode ser acessado aqui:

````
``` r
library(dplyr)
    
dados<-read.csv('https://wesleysc352.github.io/1land_use_count_hist.csv', sep = ",", header = TRUE)    
 
head(dados, 3)
#>   regiao
#> 1      1
#> 2      2
#> 3      3
#>                                                                                                                                                                                            histogram
#> 1                                  {33=67674.65490196079, 3=1155012.4039215685, 4=976901.0274509805, 15=58231.86666666672, 12=1578611.0196078431, 21=4.0, 11=276617.8666666667, 0=533990.0705882354}
#> 2                             {33=362104.8705882353, 3=1169121.4941176465, 24=4409.0, 4=1728926.3411764703, 15=324839.0078431374, 12=473555.2274509803, 11=1940289.5764705883, 0=27626.501960784328}
#> 3 {33=22532.062745098036, 3=903350.7294117648, 24=32.0, 4=1024546.0941176472, 15=27009.47058823529, 12=95827.42745098041, 41=7518.650980392157, 21=3.0, 11=233238.05098039214, 0=285137.40784313745}
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Uma sugestão é:

- remover os `{` e `}`;
- separar a string "histogram" em linhas usando como separador o `,`  (vírgula seguido de espaço em branco;
- em seguida separar essa mesma coluna em duas: "DN" e "Freq" usando como separador o `=`;
- converter o "ponto" em "vírgula":

```
dados %>% 
  mutate(histogram = str_remove_all(string = histogram, pattern = "\\{|\\}")) %>% 
  separate_rows(histogram, sep = ", ") %>% 
  separate(col = histogram, into = c("DN","Freq"),
           sep = "=", 
           convert = T) %>% 
  mutate(Freq = str_replace(string = Freq, 
                            pattern = "\\.",
                            replacement = "\\,"))
```

Resultado:

```
# A tibble: 138 × 3
   regiao    DN Freq            
    <int> <int> <chr>           
 1      1    33 67674,6549019608
 2      1     3 1155012,40392157
 3      1     4 976901,027450981
 4      1    15 58231,8666666667
 5      1    12 1578611,01960784
 6      1    21 4               
 7      1    11 276617,866666667
 8      1     0 533990,070588235
 9      2    33 362104,870588235
10      2     3 1169121,49411765
```

Comment: funcionou muito bem essa abordagem que vc usou. acabei descobrindo que essas listas são na verdade "dicionários" de dados